# Qt 5.7 \n behavior

Tags: c++, qt

In a Qt 5.7 Console Application:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString s = "MDJ\nTest.\n";
    qDebug() << "MDJ\nTest.\n";
    qDebug() << s;

    /* Prints:
        MDJ
        Test.

        MDJ\nTest.\n
    */

    return a.exec();
}
```

i.e. the \n works as expected in a direct debug print, but is treated as just two plain characters when debug printing a (supposedly identical content) variable.

I'm encountering similar problems in Qt 5.7 Widget Applications as well.

I've searched the documentation, stackoverflow, and Qt Centre and I've been unable to discover what I'm doing wrong.

Could somebody please point me to a solution for this?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-16).

Comment: @G.M. Post this as an answer.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The docs give you hints:

[`<< QString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-16)

> Normally, QDebug prints the string inside quotes and **transforms non-printable characters** to their Unicode values (\u1234).
>   To print non-printable characters without transformation, enable the `noquote()` functionality. Note that some QDebug backends might not be 8-bit clean.

vs.

[`<< const char*`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-15)

> Writes the '\0'-terminated string, s, to the stream and returns a reference to the stream. The string **is never quoted nor transformed** to the output, but note that some QDebug backends might not be 8-bit clean.

Solution: `qDebug().noquote() << "some\nspecial\nchars\n\tincluded"`